# Configure Emacs for Web Development (PHP)

Tags: php, javascript, css, emacs

I am trying to use Emacs as a beginner. I want to configure it for web development.

I want syntax-highlighting for PHP, Javascript, HTML, CSS, and also I want (project wide)code completion.

Can anyone please guide me where to start? What packages must be installed? Any guides on the installation and configuration?
I am running GNU Emacs 23.2.1 on Debian Squeeze.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate on 'project-wide code completion'? e.g. Are you wanting to be able to complete PHP built-ins as well as custom code? For custom code completion, a TAGS (or GNU Global) based solution is the typical approach. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565603 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/912671/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript, HTML, and CSS are all syntax-highlighted out of the box. The problem is that you will be writing PHP files that intermix all of those, which is a real pain even if you do set up one of the multiple-mode modes.

You can improve things over the defaults, however. For Javascript I recommend installing [`js2-mode`](http://code.google.com/p/js2-mode/); it's got better syntax highlighting, indentation, and error reporting than the built-in javascript mode. For HTML I've always used [`nxml-mode`](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/), which has lately become the default. It's been ages since I've done anything with PHP, so I don't have any personal recommendations for that. However, I notice something called [`nxhtml-mode`](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) which looks quite interesting. It looks like `nxml-mode` upgraded to better support XHTML specifically (as opposed to XML generically), complete with a [`MuMaMo`](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html#php) setup for handling CSS, Javascript, and even PHP. Looks like it'd be a good choice.

I've never really set up any code completion in Emacs, I look forward to seeing everyone else's answers.

Comment: There's no out-of-the-box php-mode in Emacs 23.

Comment: And conversely, nxml-mode *is* included by default, and it is the default mode for editing XML (as of 23.2). Which version of Emacs are you running, db48x?

Comment: Ah, that's good news; my Emacs configuration is pretty old even if I have upgraded fairly regularly.

Answer (score 1):

As db48x suggested, the `nxhtml-mode` is the way to go. It will support highlighting different regions of your file using different rules (using MuMaMo). It's not perfect but more than enough for usual HTML+other languages in a single file work.

I don't use code completion but I use [auto-complete.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) and am quite happy with it. It's not language aware but I don't usually use that. Works mostly out of the box.

My own (rather messy) config files are on [github](https://github.com/nibrahim/Config-files) if you want to take a look.